# Getting the exact edited data from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two Tables:

1. `Articles(artID, artContents, artPublishDate, artCategoryID, publisherID)`.
2. `ArticleUpdated(upArtID, upArtContents, upArtEditedData, upArtPublishDate, upArtCategory, upArtOriginalArticleID, upPublisherID)`

   **A user logging in to the application and update an article's
   contents at (artContents) column. I want to know about:**

   1. Which Changes the user made to the article's contents?
   2. I want to store both versions of the Article, Original version and Edited Version!

**What should I do for doing above two task:**

- Any necessary changes into the tables?
- The query for getting exact edited data of `(artContents)`.

  - (The exact edited data means, that there may 5000 characters in the coloumns, the user may edit 200 characters in the middle or somewhere else in column's characters, I want exact those edited characters, before of edit and after of edit)

*Note: I am using ASP.NET with C# for Developing*

Comment: I can't think of other solution other than saving the edited text to a different column just like your original table.

Comment: There is a whole [`Change Tracking`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) feature in SQL Server. You might want to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to do the exact editing using SQL.  You need an algorithm such as  the Unix `diff` on files (which works on the line level).  At the character level, the algorithm would be some variation of [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).  If `diff` meets your needs, you could download it, write a stored-procedure to call it, and then use it in the database.  This would be rather expensive.

The part of your question of maintaining the different versions is much easier.  I would add two colmnns `EffDate` and `EndDate` onto each record.  You can get the most recent version by looking for `EndDate is NULL` and find the version active at any given time.  `Merge` is generally useful for maintaining such a table.

Comment: my requirement is specified in this link, please take a look on this and then write your comment or solution, thanks for your help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855254/how-to-handle-track-changes-as-stack-overflow-edited-article)

Answer (score 0):

Basically this type for requirement needs custom logging.

The example what you have provided i.e. "The exact edited data means, that there may 5000 characters in the coloumns, the user may edit 200 characters in the middle or somewhere else in column's characters, I want exact those edited characters, before of edit and after of edit"

Can have a case that user updates particular words from different place from the text.

You can use http://nlog-project.org/ for logging, its a fast and robust tool that normally we use for doing .net logging.

Also you can take a look
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38756/Two-Simple-Approaches-to-WinForms-Dirty-Tracking
[Asp.net Event for change tracking of entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915574/asp-net-event-for-change-tracking-of-entities)
[What would be the best way to implement change tracking on an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363801/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-implement-change-tracking-on-an-object)

Above urls will clear some air, on how to do it.

You would obviously need to track down and store every change.